# Does the number meet the condition of the equation?

Tags: logarithms

I needed to replace a solution in the equation, to see if it was correct.

The two solutions of this equation: $log_5{(x+3)} + log_5{(12x + 1)} = 3$,

are:  {${\frac{-61}{12}, 2}$}

The solution $2$, satisfy the equation, but with $\frac{-61}{12}$ is the problem.

My development to replace in a image:

[image]

In step 2, I specifically marked it with a circle. My teacher says that it does not satisfy, since there are no negative logarithms, but if I continue to develop the equation, it remains as positive and if it satisfies, then who is wrong?

Comment: $logA+logB=log(AB)$ is only true if $A>0$ and $B>0$

Comment: Please multiply the figure by $i$.

Comment: And what is $A < 0$ and $B < 0$ ? so $ (- * - = + )$

Comment: What ? why $i$?

Comment: In your course, the logarithm of a negative number does not exist. The logarithm has to exist in order to apply the standard rules of logarithms. Rafa's comment (please ignore!) is not going to change that

Comment: In addition, you may want to resort to a graphing tool to graph $y=log_5{(x+3)} + log_5{(12x + 1)} $ and look at the graph to see where it crosses the line $y=3$. There will be only one solution

Comment: "but if I continue to develop the equation"... you can't "continue to develop" if you are at point where something is impossible.  A unicorn is a myth but cheese is not.  If I take a unicorn, milk it and make cheese, I can't claim the end result, cheese, is okay.  I can't have cheese, because I had to use a unicorn to get there.  And unicorns don't exist.  In the same way you can't add two logarithms of negative numbers together and get a logarithm of a positive number.  You used negative numbers to get there, and logs of negatives don't exist.

Comment: "Please multiply the figure by i." "What ? why i?".  The guy is making a joke.  He is saying "please rotate the image counterclockwise by 90 degress".  If you multiply a complex number by $i$ the resulting (when graphed on the complex plane) is a 90 degree rotation of the original number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conditions of the equation are

$$x+3>0$$
and
$$12x+1>0.$$

which could be replaced by 
$$x>\frac {-1}{12} $$

but $$\frac {-61}{12}<\frac {-1}{12} $$
and is not a solution.